# how to avoid ambiguous column name in spark dataframe after a drop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, avro

I use pyspark 2.
In my schema i have a duplicate column names : "IRLS" AND "irls"
I read my avro file:

```
data=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(data_path)
```

I drop the columns and reassign :

```
delete=['IRLS','irls']
data=data.drop(*delete)
```

I see that the duplicated columns have disappeared after a

```
data.printSchema()
```

But when i try to read one column of the dataframe, i still get the duplicate error

data.select(data.env).take(2)

```
"Reference 'IRLS' is ambiguous, could be: IRLS#4413, IRLS#4422.;"
```

Comment: Let's say you had three columns - `env`, `IRLS` & `irls`. So, after you delete `IRLS` & `irls` you are left with only `env`. Now, when you run the query `data.select(data.env).take(2) ` you get the error message you mentioned above, right? Is that what you are claiming? I am trying to reproduce it at my end, so just want to be sure.

Comment: Exactly. I have only one column left.But i still get an error

Comment: Please run this code by indenting it and let me know - `values = [('A',22,31),('B',2,1),('C',4,1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['env','IRIS','iris'])
df.show()
df = df.drop('IRIS','iris')
df.show()
df.printSchema()
df.select(df.env).take(2)` Do you get error now?

Comment: It works. No error. I have only 'env' as column at the end.

Comment: Is it because the underlying format of my dataframe is avro?

Comment: Well, I find it hard to believe that `avro` could make a difference once the data has been read into the `dataframe`. There should be no difference I believe so. Can you paste your complete code here, including the `import` statement?

Comment: Finally i found a workaround. By setting: `spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=True`)